# Merging tables on specific fields in PrestoDB

Tags: sql, presto, sql-merge

I want to combine two different tables.

**table1**

| name | id | type | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| name1 | 1 | a | 08-17 |
| name2 | 2 | b | 08-17 |

**table2**

| name | id | date | attribute_1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| name1 | 1 | 08-18 | attr_id_1 |
| name2 | 2 | 08-18 | attr_id_2 |

The two tables have in common "*name*" and "*id*" fields (used for mapping the records) and the field "*date*" is the partition key for both.

I need to carry out two operations:

- add a column in table1
- insert the records with "*attribute_1*" in table2

**Expected Output**:

| name | id | type | date | attribute_1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| name1 | 1 | a | 08-17 |  |
| name2 | 2 | b | 08-17 |  |
| name1 | 1 | a | 08-18 | attr_id_1 |
| name2 | 2 | b | 08-18 | attr_id_2 |

The inserted records should be in the new partition (new "*date*"). The "*type*" column in output table is duplicated from table1(actually there are other fields like "*type*" in table1 but for simplicity I just list one of them), it's  like updating the rows in table1 with the "*attribute_1*" field, then insert the updated rows back into table1.

I've looked at the `INSERT INTO` command in the official documentation but it seems that there is no such operation that does it all, what should I do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you generate the "*type*" field for table2 values in your output? What's the rationale behind those values?

Comment: Actually it's like duplicate the record in table1, and append the "attribute_1" in table2

Answer (score 1):

You can split the problem into two queries, namely:

- an [`ALTER TABLE`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/alter-table.html) statement, to change the schema of table1
- an [`INSERT`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/insert.html) statement, to add rows from table2 to table1

The select statement inside the insert will require a join operation to generate "*table1.type*" values on table2. The match is carried out on the fields "*name*" and "*id*".

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS attribute_1 <same type of table2.attribute1>;

INSERT INTO table1 
SELECT t2.name, 
       t2.id,
       t1.type, 
       t2.date,
       t2.attribute_1
FROM       table2 t2
INNER JOIN table1 t1
        ON t2.name = t1.name AND t2.id = t1.id
```